# boost::Serialize VS std::fstream

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, save, fstream

Hey so i guess i'm a little confused on the purpose of boost::serialize:

Having to add a boost::serialize function to every class you plan to save seems to kind of defeat the purpose of the library, as instead of *boosting*/ decreasing development time it seems like it would add a HUGE amount of time since you have to go in and *edit the source of every class in every library your using so it has a Serialization function.*

I was planning on using it for a SFML/Box2D game, but now i'm having second thoughts once i think this through.... **I'm i using the library wrong?**

**It seems like std::fstream would be a much better idea**, as that doesn't require any functions or changes to be made to whatever class you want to save, and i could design a "**Save class**."

Comment: Wouldn't you be adding code to each class anyway when using `std::fstream`? How would you go about saving, for example, an `std::vector`? `boost::serialize` already knows `vector`s and other standard library containers, which you would otherwise have to write yourself

Comment: @Pablo: no, fstream doesn't require anything except the size of the class at atual save time, i would assume it has no real knowledge of the class other than how much data to output to a file, and how much to put back in at load-time

Comment: @Grifin: That method (treating an object as a string of bytes and writing that to file) is not portable, easily breaks and should not be used in production code, unless you have a really good reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing directly to a standard stream would still require you to write a serialization/deserialization function pair. Not only the iostream component of the standard library does not support I/O of custom classes, but just writing and reading back sizeof(yourObject) bytes wouldn't work. Just think about what would happen if your class contained pointer members.

Moreover the serialization library provides feature like support for different formats and versioning, which may be useful.

Comment: i'm a little worried about editing SFML/Box2D's source code, should i just suck it up and attempt it?

Comment: This tutorial: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html provides an example of how to do it without modifying your original classes.

Comment: "Only classes which expose enough information to save and restore the class state will be serializable without changing the class definition" By "enough info" does it mean all member variables need to be public to be saved?

Comment: @Griffin: I think you have some misunderstanding about serialization, and I think those misunderstandings would begin to be resolved if you asked a question about a specific object you want saved.  If you are using a class that has private data, and it doesn't already have it's own serialization functions, then you probably don't have to worry about those private data members.  You see, you don't have to save every single bit contained in your object, you just need to save the parts that are necessary to reconstruct it.

Comment: @Griffin: it's up to you know what part of each class state you need to save in order to restore each of its instances correctly. Maybe you should take a different approach and rather than think about how to save objects from classes in a library, consider first in a more abstract way what information you need to say. You might end up defining some form of configuration file and then use the information you read from that file to recreate your object hierarchy exactly as you did the first time around.

Answer (score 6):

Er, what? Boost.Serialization is not a replacement for I/O streams. It's a framework for serialisation (i.e. saving and restoring the state of an object from an external storage), the archives still wrap some kind of stream to actually read and write data. Of course you need to write serialising functions, the library has no way of knowing where the data, or how should it be layed out in the archive otherwise — if you'd use `fstream`, whatever that means in this context, you'd still have to do the same. You don't necessarily need to implement the save/load functions as class members, either — the documentation says how to make them as free functions.

Comment: but the libraries classes dont have public data members, and what do you mean i need to write serialising functions? all fstream requires is the number of bites to load/take from a class.

Comment: @Grifin: Again, naively using `ostream::write` to serialise objects is *wrong*, even if it happens to work for simple cases.

Comment: So i should just suck it up and edit the source code? what do people do when the source is not open?

Comment: @Griffin: If you do that, there is no guarantee that you will be able to load it again. Even between debug and release builds, there can be differences. Also, if it is a virtual class, you're screwed since you will have overwritten the v-table pointer and thus destroyed the class. Honestly, if writing and reading a class to/from a file were as simple as blasting the bits out and reading them back, do you think that large libraries like Boost.Serialization would have been written at all?

Comment: @Grifin: And again, you don't need to edit original classes to serialise them. Read Boost.Serialization documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like std::fstream would be a much better idea, as that doesn't require any functions or changes to be made to whatever class you want to save, and i could design a "Save class."

A better idea to do what?

Serialization is typically used for saving and restoring the state of objects, not arbitrary data. It's purpose is to be able to take a bag of objects and produce a file, such that these objects can be automatically reconstructed from that file at a later date.

If you can collate all of the information you want to save into a "save class", then you don't *need* serialization.

Also, you cannot just write a class to a stream; you would have to implement a `operator<<` overload or some other function to save its data and load it back. Yes, you could just throw the bits of the object out with `memcpy`, but that's not exactly safe. And by "not exactly safe", I mean "you should never do this unless you really, *really* know what you're doing."